# CakePHP: Lowercase password on AuthComponent

Tags: cakephp

I had to import a bunch of members and had to apply `strtolower()` to their passwords before encrypting them in the DB. Now, in order for members to be able to login, I need to apply `strtolower()` to `$this->request->data['Member']['password']`. How can I do this?

Comment: Why did you strtolower? You just made their passwords less secure.

Answer (score 0):

Put the function for lowering in the Model's "beforeSave" function.

```
public function beforeSave(array $options = array()){
     //code for lowering here
}
```

Documentation about callbacks functions are [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html).

EDIT:

You can do this in your Controller in your login function:

```
$this->request->data['User']['password'] = function_for_lowering($this->request->data['User']['password']);
```

The password would then be lowercase and then the login should apply.

Comment: OP stated he/she already did this. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: function_for_lowering? How about strtolower :)

Comment: I didn't use it so I just wrote function_for_lowering. ^^

Answer (score 0):

In your login method:

```
if (!empty($this->request->data) {

    $this->request->data['User']['password'] = strtolower($this->request->data['User']['password']);

    // procceed with login...

}
```